# Using RegEx to Extract Anchor Text of Links With Beginning of Specific Target URL

Tags: regex

I need assistance with capturing "Mr. John Doe" from the following HTML code:

```
<a href="/author/john-doe.htm"> Mr. John Doe </a>
```

I have been trying various string matching and thought that I was close when I tried using the following RegEx:

```
<a href="\/author\/.* .htm">(.*)</a>
```

...But, no matches were found in the capturing group.

This is something I'm trying to set as a parameter in a crawl simulation software (using PCRE). I'm simply looking to extract the author name which would appear within a hyperlink that links to a target URL beginning with /author/...

Any pointers? Thank you in advance!

Comment: You [**require a space when there's none**](https://regex101.com/r/zNpMUu/1). However, if you're still at the beginning, better use a prser and xpath queries instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you require a space when there's none:

```
<a href="\/author\/.* .htm">(.*)</a>
#                   ^^^
```

[**Remove it and it works**](https://regex101.com/r/zNpMUu/1/):

```
<a href="\/author\/.*.htm">(.*)</a>
```

However, this expression could be vastly optimized (no dot-star-soup everywhere, that is) and if you're still at the beginning, better use a parser and xpath queries instead.